# System of two moduli

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Compute which element $[0],[1],\ldots,[2014]$  in $\Bbb{Z}/2015\Bbb{Z}$ under the map of the  Chinese remainder theorem is mapped to $([12],[5])\in\Bbb{Z}/31\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}/65\Bbb{Z}$.
$$                           x=12 \pmod{31} 
\\
                           x=5 \pmod{65}
$$
I used the Euclidean algorithm to find $\gcd(31,65)= 31n+65m=1$ for $n= 21$ and $m= -10$. Now $x=12 \cdot 65 \cdot (-10) + 5 \cdot 31 \cdot 21 = -7800 +3255 =-4545 = [1500]$.

My question is: how do I find that $-4545= [1500]$?

Answer (score 2):

$$x=12 \pmod{31} \implies x = 12+31k \implies$$

$$12+31k=5 \pmod{65} \implies k = 48 \implies x = 1500$$

Comment: How did you get $k=48?$

Comment: You have to solve $31k=-7 \pmod{65}$ for $k$. Since $31^{-1} = 21 \pmod{65}$, you multiply both sides to obtain $k = 48 \pmod{65}.$

Answer (score 1):

$-4545=((-3)\times2015)+1500$

$ \Rightarrow -4545\equiv 1500 ($mod $2015)$

Answer (score 0):

To find the equivalence class of $-4545$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2015\mathbb{Z}$, we must find $x \in \left\{0, 1, ..., 2014\right\}$ for which $k \cdot 2015 = x - 4545$ holds for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. By this definition, we have $-4545 \in [x]$.

Clearly, this holds for $k = -3$ and $x = 1500$, so we have $-4545 \in [1500]$.